# Paypal Recurring Profile: how to run cycle every hour?

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I am using ExpressCheckout.

- **SetExpressCheckout**
- **DoExpressCheckoutPayment**
- **GetExpressCheckoutDetails**
- **CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile**

Above api call and run perfectly.

I want my cycle run every run.

**BILLINGPERIOD** not provide hour option how i can do that?

[Reference link](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments/#recurring-payments-profile-options)

Answer (score 0):

For something like that you would need to skip the recurring payments API and setup a billing agreement instead.

This will give you a Billing Agreement ID which can then be passed into DoReferenceTransaction to process future payments of any amount at any time.

You'll need to get Billing Agreements specifically approved and enabled on your PayPal account in order to do this.